# C# - Ordenar Array

Tags: c#, array, ordenar

estoy con un ejercicio de C# en el que se me pide eliminar un numero repetido, reemplazarlo por cero y enviarlo al final del array. Pude realizar todo excepto el ordenamiento del array, donde no se permite utilizar un array secundario. Alguien me podría dar una mano?

pd: no se permite utilizar bibliotecas, ya que se trata de introducción a la programación y la idea sería entender la lógica.

mi código en cuestión:

```
    namespace Segundo_Parcial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[8];
            LlenarArray(array);
            MostrarArray(array);
            EliminarNumero(array);
            MostrarArray(array);
            OrdenarArray(array);
            MostrarArray(array);
        }


    static void LlenarArray(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese el número que irá en la posición " + i + ": ");
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("==================");
    }
    static void MostrarArray(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Posición " + i + " = " + array[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("====================");
    }

    static void EliminarNumero(int[] array)
    {
        int numeroAEliminar;
        Console.Write("Ingrese el número a eliminar: ");
        numeroAEliminar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == numeroAEliminar)
            {
                array[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    static void OrdenarArray(int[] array)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)
            {
               
            }
           
        
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: si vas a eliminar duplicados, y ordenar a la vez, tal vez ordenamiento por inserción te sirva (que es un algoritmo muy versátil y en algunos casos muy muy eficiente)

Comment: Podrías utilizar la función OrderBy o OrderByDescending: array = array.OrderBy(e=> e).ToArray(); Para agregar el 0 puedes utilizar Append

Comment: hola @naccsgo podrias decirme si la respuesta te resulto util, gracias

Comment: hola @japv muchas gracias por responder, me sirvió muchísimo y ya pude resolver el ejercicio!! mil gracias!!!!!

Comment: @naccsgo si la respuesta te resultó útil marcala como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respondo atendiendo a tu diseño(que puede mejorarse muchísimo)**:

Dentro de tu **función EliminarNumero** la **variable  tamanoArray** que servirá para ir actualizando el tamaño del arreglo a medida que vayamos eliminando elementos del mismo. Cada vez que se elimine un elemento del arreglo la **variable tamanoArray** disminuirá en **1** su valor, es decir encontramos el elemento a eliminar dentro del arreglo en la **posición i**, esta **posición i** la actualizamos con el valor de la última posición del arreglo, y le damos a la última posición del arreglo el valor **0**, entonces se decrementa en **1** el valor de la **variable tamanoArray** y ya en la siguiente eliminación se intercambiaría el valor a eliminar por la nueva última posición del arreglo almacenada en la **variable tamanoArray**.

Posteriormente dentro de la misma **función EliminarNumero** llamamos a la **función OrdenarArray**, la cual ahora recibirá **2** parámetros: el arreglo a ordenar y el tamaño del arreglo. Esta función utiliza el **método burbuja** para ordenar el arreglo de manera ascendente. Puedes investigar más sobre el **método burbuja** en Internet.

```
static void EliminarNumero(int[] array)
{
    int numeroAEliminar;
    Console.Write("Ingrese el número a eliminar: ");
    numeroAEliminar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int tamanoArray = array.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == numeroAEliminar)
        {
            array[i] = array[tamanoArray - 1];
            array[tamanoArray - 1] = 0;
            tamanoArray--;
        }            
    }

    OrdenarArray(array, tamanoArray);
}

static void OrdenarArray(int[] array, int tamanoArray)
{
    int tmp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < tamanoArray; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < tamanoArray - 1; j++)
        {
            if(array[j] > array[j + 1])
            {
                tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finalmente para para hacer lo que pide tu ejercicio pondrías este código dentro del **método Main**:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[8];

    LlenarArray(array);
    MostrarArray(array);
    EliminarNumero(array);
    MostrarArray(array);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Una solucíon simple para eliminar duplicados y a su vez ordenarlo es modificar [ordenación por inserción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151088/ordenaci%C3%B3n-por-inserci%C3%B3n-duda).

Esta ordenación considera a la parte izquierda del arreglo como ordenado.

La única modificación que debes hacer es que si ya encuentras un valor en la parte izquierda ordenada, entonces no lo insertes, simplemente reemplázalo con 0 y ponlo al final.

Un ejemplo:

```
8 3 4 3 1
```

Al ordenar:

**8** 3 4 3 1      // Primer elemento ordenado

**3 8** 4 3 1      // 3 insertado

**3 4 8** 3 1      // 4 insertado

**3 4 8** 1 0      // al intentar insertar 3, vemos que esta repetido entonces omitir y poner 0 al final

**3 4 8 1** 0      // insertar 1, y terminar

Y así se logra con relativa eficiencia tanto eliminar duplicados como ordenar.

Comment: no termino de entender, doy el ejemplo de ejercicio que tengo:

Posible lote de prueba: 8 23 32 9 32 9 108 47

Valor a eliminar: 32

Arreglo resultante: 8 23 9 9 108 47 0 0

Comment: quieres eliminar no mas? o ordenar y eliminar? En un sentido ordenar y eliminar es mas facil que solo eliminar.. Pero solo eliminar lo puedes lograr recorriendo y buscando entre todos los elementos de la izquierda si ya esta el elemento, y si no lo eliminas.

Comment: el ejercicio pide llenar un array, ingresar un valor a eliminar en el array, que ese valor a eliminar valga 0 y ese cero dejarlo al final del array, y mostrar el array final
edit: pude hacer todo, lo unico que no puedo es tomar ese valor 0 y enviarlo al final del array (no puedo usar array auxiliar, de esa manera si puedo hacerlo...)

Comment: manten un puntero "fin" que apunta a la posicion final del arreglo. Cuando tienes que "eliminar" mueves el valor de arreglo[fin] a donde esta el valor, y arreglo[fin]=0. Luego fin--.
Haces eso hasta que la posicion actual sea mayor que fin, y ahi termina.